# How do I replace title with my plugin?

Tags: plugin-development, filters, hooks, wp-title

I am developing a plugin for WordPress 3.5. My blog's default title is "Test". Here is some code of my plugin:

```
add_filter('wp_title', 'my_replace_title');

function my_replace_title(){
    return get_option('my_site_title');
}
```

The new title is "my website title". But it's out putting the result:

"my website titleTest"

How to replace old title with new title?

Comment: To which title are you referring: 1. Site Title, 2. Page Title, 3. Post Title ?

Comment: Make sure the `Test` part is not hard-coded in your theme.

Comment: @BrianFegter Site Title

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code hope it will solve your problem.

```
add_filter( 'wp_title', 'theme_custom_title', 20 );

function theme_custom_title $title ) {
    return str_replace('your old title', 'your New title', $title); 
}
```

```
// changes the "Enter title here" to "Enter some New title" 
add_filter('gettext', 'custom_rewrites', 10, 4);
```

```
function custom_rewrites($translation, $text, $domain) {
    global $post;
    $translations = &get_translations_for_domain($domain);
    $translation_array = array();
    switch ($post->post_type) {
        case 'videofaqs':
            $translation_array = array(
                'Enter title here' => 'Enter Video question here'
            );
            break;
    }
    if (array_key_exists($text, $translation_array)) {
        return $translations->translate($translation_array[$text]);
    }
    return $translation;
}
```